# How can I modify registry with stack in assembly language(MIPS)?

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I am having a problem with a register in assembly language. I can't seem to understand how to modify the registry with stacks from my original program. I'm using MIPS.

What I have to do is basically this:

Modify so that it uses stack to pass arguments IN and OUT. again, $a and $v registers should not be used to pass arguments. Only stack should be used. Please do not modify the logic of code, only change what is needed to use stack.

```
#       Register Usage
#   $t0
#   $t1
#   $t2
#   $t3
#   $t4
#   $t5
#   $t6
#   $t7
#   $t8
#   $t9     temporarily
###########################################################
        .data
array_pointer_p:        .word 0     # holds address of dynamic array (address)
array_size_p:           .word 0     # hold size of dynamic array (value)        
array_sum_p:            .word 0     # sum variable initialized to 0
###########################################################
        .text
main:
# calling subprogram read_values
    jal make_array                      # call read_values subprogram
                                        # arguments IN: NONE
                                        # arguments OUT: array base address and size

# store returned values (array base address & size) into static variables
    la $t9, array_pointer_p             # load the address of variable array_pointer_p into register $t9
    sw $v0, 0($t9)                      # store the true address of dynamic array into static variable
                                        # memory[0 + array_pointer_p] <-- $v0

    la $t9, array_size_p                # load the address of variable array_size_p into register $t9
    sw $v1, 0($t9)                      # store value of array into static variable
                                        # memory[0 + array_size_p] <-- $v1


# load array base address & size from static variables
    la $t9, array_pointer_p             # load the address of variable array_pointer_p into register $t9
    lw $a0, 0($t9)                      # load the true address of dynamic array into static variable
                                        # $a0 <-- memory[0 + array_pointer_p]

    la $t9, array_size_p                # load the address of variable array_size_p into register $t9
    lw $a1, 0($t9)                      # store value of array into static variable
                                        # $a1 <-- memory[0 + array_size_p]

# calling subprogram read_values
    jal read_values                     # call read_values subprogram
                                        # arguments IN: array base address and size
                                        # arguments OUT: array sum

# store returned values (array sum) into static variables
    la $t9, array_sum_p                 # load the address of variable array_sum_p into register $t9
    sw $v0, 0($t9)                      # store value of array sum into static variable
                                        # memory[0 + array_sum_p] <-- $v0


# load array base address & size from static variables
    la $t9, array_pointer_p             # load the address of variable array_pointer_p into register $t9
    lw $a0, 0($t9)                      # load the true address of dynamic array into static variable
                                        # $a0 <-- memory[0 + array_pointer_p]

    la $t9, array_size_p                # load the address of variable array_size_p into register $t9
    lw $a1, 0($t9)                      # store value of array into static variable
                                        # $a1 <-- memory[0 + array_size_p]

# calling subprogram read_values
    jal print_backwards                 # call read_values subprogram
                                        # arguments IN: array base address and size
                                        # arguments OUT: NONE


# load array sum & size from static variables
    la $t9, array_sum_p                 # load the address of variable array_sum_p into register $t9
    lw $a0, 0($t9)                      # load value of array sum into static variable
                                        # $a0 <-- memory[0 + array_sum_p]

    la $t9, array_size_p                # load the address of variable array_size_p into register $t9
    lw $a1, 0($t9)                      # store value of array size into static variable
                                        # $a1 <-- memory[0 + array_size_p]

# calling subprogram read_values
    jal print_average                   # call read_values subprogram
                                        # arguments IN: array sum and size
                                        # arguments OUT: NONE

mainEnd:    
    li $v0, 10                          # halt
    syscall
###########################################################
#       make_array subprogram
#
#   Subprogram description:
#       The first subprogram 'make_array' will ask the user for the number of integers to be
#       read and dynamically declares an array to hold them. It receives no arguments IN and
#       has two arguments OUT, the base address of the dynamically declared array and it size.
#       Do not forget to validate array size (array size should be greater than zero).
#
###########################################################
#       Arguments IN and OUT of subprogram
#   $a0
#   $a1
#   $a2
#   $a3
#   $v0     Holds array pointer (address)
#   $v1     Holds array size (value)
#   $sp
#   $sp+4
#   $sp+8
#   $sp+12
###########################################################
#       Register Usage
#   $t0  Holds array pointer (address)
#   $t1  Holds array size pointer (address)
#   $t2  Holds array size, temporarily  
###########################################################
        .data
make_array_prompt_p:    .asciiz "Enter size of the array to allocate (greater than 0): "
make_array_invalid_p:   .asciiz "Array size you entered is incorrect (array size should be greater than zero)\n"
###########################################################
        .text
make_array:

make_array_loop:
    li $v0, 4                           # prompt for array size
    la $a0, make_array_prompt_p
    syscall

    li $v0, 5                           # reads integer for array size
    syscall

    blez $v0, make_array_invalid_size   # branch to error section as array size is less than or equal to zero

    move $t2, $v0                       # store valid array size in register $t2

    li $v0, 9                           # dynamically allocate an array (using system call 9)
    move $a0, $t2                       # puts array size in register $a0
    sll $a0, $a0, 2                     # multiply array size by 4, as word in MIPS is 4 bytes
    syscall

    b make_array_end                    # branch unconditionally to the end of subprogram

make_array_invalid_size:
    li $v0, 4                           # prints an error saying that array size is less than or equal to zero
    la $a0, make_array_invalid_p
    syscall

    b make_array_loop                   # branch unconditionally back to beginning of the loop

make_array_end:
    move $v0, $v0                       # return address of dynamic array in register $v0 (array_pointer)
    move $v1, $t2                       # store size of dynamic array in register $v1 (array_size)

    jr $ra                              # jump back to the main
###########################################################
#       read_values subprogram
#
#   Subprogram description:
#       The second subprogram 'read_values' which receives two arguments IN, the array base address
#       and its size. Also, it makes sure entered numbers are between 0 and +250 exclusive. It returns
#       (OUT) the sum of valid numbers read in the appropriate registers.
#
###########################################################
#       Arguments IN and OUT of subprogram
#   $a0
#   $a1
#   $a2
#   $a3
#   $v0     Holds sum
#   $v1
#   $sp
#   $sp+4
#   $sp+8
#   $sp+12
###########################################################
#       Register Usage
#   $t0     Holds array base address / array pointer
#   $t1     Holds array size / loop count down
#   $t2     Holds sum
#   $t3     Holds value -120
#   $t4     Holds value 150
###########################################################
        .data
read_values_prompt_p:   .asciiz "Enter a value between (-120 to +150) exclusive: "
read_values_invalid_p:  .asciiz "Invalid entry\n"
###########################################################
        .text
read_values:
# store arguments IN into temporarily registers so we don't lose them
    move $t0, $a0                       # array base address        
    move $t1, $a1                       # array size

# initialization
    li $t2, 0                           # initialize sum to 0
    li $t3, -120                        # holds value -120
    li $t4, 150                         # holds value 150

read_values_loop:
    blez $t1, read_values_exit_loop     # branch to the read_values_exit_loop if loop counter is 
                                        # less than or equal to zero

    li $v0, 4                           # prompts to enter a value
    la $a0, read_values_prompt_p
    syscall

    li $v0, 5                           # reads an integer value
    syscall

    bge $v0, $t4, read_values_error     # branch to the error if value if greater
                                        # than or equal to 150

    ble $v0, $t3, read_values_error     # branch to the error if value if less
                                        # than or equal to -120

    add $t2, $t2, $v0                   # adds the number to the sum

    sw $v0, 0($t0)                      # store the number in the array

    addi $t0, $t0, 4                    # increment array pointer (address) to next word (each word is 4 bytes)
    addi $t1, $t1, -1                   # decrement array count down (index)  by 1

    b read_values_no_error              # branch unconditionally to no_error label to
                                        # skip printing error massage for valid entries

read_values_error:
    li $v0, 4                           # prints an error message
    la $a0, read_values_invalid_p
    syscall

read_values_no_error:
    b read_values_loop                  # branch unconditionally to the beginning of the loop

read_values_exit_loop:
    move $v0, $t2                       # return sum in register $v0

read_values_end:
    jr $ra                              # jump back to the main
###########################################################
#      print_backwards subprogram
#
#   Subprogram description:
#       The third subprogram 'print_backwards' receives as arguments IN the base address of the
#       array and its size. It has no arguments OUT. It outputs the array in reverse order one number
#       per line at a time.
#
###########################################################
#       Arguments IN and OUT of subprogram
#   $a0     Holds array pointer (address)
#   $a1     Holds array size (value)
#   $a2
#   $a3
#   $v0
#   $v1
#   $sp
#   $sp+4
#   $sp+8
#   $sp+12
###########################################################
#       Register Usage
#   $t0     Holds array base address / array pointer
#   $t1     Holds array size / loop count down
#   $t2     temporarily
###########################################################
        .data
print_backwards_array_p:    .asciiz     "Array (in backwards): "
print_backwards_nextline_p: .asciiz     "\n" 
###########################################################
        .text
print_backwards:
# store arguments IN into temporarily registers so we don't lose them
    move $t0, $a0                       # move array pointer (address) to $t0
    move $t1, $a1                       # move array size (value) to $t1

# adjust array base address: new base address = old base address + 4 * (count - 1)
    add $t2, $t1, -1                    # adjust count (n) to last element index (n-1)
    sll $t2, $t2, 2                     # multiply element index number by element size (4 bytes)
    add $t0, $t0, $t2                   # address of last element

    li $v0, 4                           # prints array is:
    la $a0, print_backwards_array_p
    syscall

    li $v0, 4                           # prints nextline ("\n")
    la $a0, print_backwards_nextline_p
    syscall

print_backwards_loop:
    blez $t1, print_backwards_exit_loop # branch to print_backwards_exit_loop if counter is less than or equal to zero

# print value from array
    li $v0, 1
    lw $a0, 0($t0)                      # $a0 <-- memory[$t0 + 0] // load a value from memory to register $a0
    syscall

    li $v0, 4                           # prints nextline ("\n")
    la $a0, print_backwards_nextline_p
    syscall

    addi $t0, $t0, -4                   # decrement array pointer (address) to next word (each word is 4 bytes)
    addi $t1, $t1, -1                   # decrement array counter (index)

    b print_backwards_loop              # branch unconditionally back to beginning of the loop

print_backwards_exit_loop:
    li $v0, 4                           # prints nextline ("\n")
    la $a0, print_backwards_nextline_p
    syscall

print_backwards_end:    
    jr $ra                              # jump back to the main
###########################################################
#      print_average subprogram
#
#   Subprogram description:
#       The fourth subprogram 'print_average' which receives as arguments IN the 'total' and 'count'
#       and has no arguments OUT. It outputs the average of the numbers read to 5 decimal places using
#       only integer commands. You will declare and use static variables to hold the base address of the
#       array, count of element, and the sum of values of the elements.
#
###########################################################
#       Arguments IN and OUT of subprogram
#   $a0     Holds array sum (value)
#   $a1     Holds array size (value)
#   $a2
#   $a3
#   $v0
#   $v1
#   $sp
#   $sp+4
#   $sp+8
#   $sp+12
###########################################################
#       Register Usage
#   $t0     holds sum/remainder
#   $t1     holds count
#   $t2     holds default number of decimal points (constant value 7)
#   $t3     holds constant value 10
###########################################################
        .data
print_average_sum_p:        .asciiz     "Given sum: "
print_average_count_p:      .asciiz     "Given count: "
print_average_average_p:    .asciiz     "Array average (up-to 7 decimal points using integer instructions): "
print_average_nextline_p:   .asciiz     "\n" 
###########################################################
        .text
print_average:
# store arguments IN into temporarily registers so we don't lose them
    move $t0, $a0                       # move array sum to $t0
    move $t1, $a1                       # move array size (value) to $t1

# initialization
    li $t2, 5                           # calculate average up-to 7 digit accuracy
    li $t3, 10                          # initialize $t2 to constant value 10

# print sum
    li $v0, 4                           # print sum is:
    la $a0, print_average_sum_p
    syscall

    li $v0, 1                           # print sum value
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall

# print nextline
    li $v0, 4                           # prints nextline ("\n")
    la $a0, print_average_nextline_p
    syscall

# print count
    li $v0, 4                           # print count is:
    la $a0, print_average_count_p
    syscall

    li $v0, 1                           # print count value
    move $a0, $t1
    syscall

# print nextline
    li $v0, 4                           # prints nextline ("\n")
    la $a0, print_average_nextline_p
    syscall

# print average 
    li $v0, 4                           # print average is:
    la $a0, print_average_average_p
    syscall

    div $t0, $t1                        # divide sum by count
    mflo $a0                            # put quotient in register $a0
    mfhi $t0                            # put remainder in register $t0

    li $v0, 1                           # print quotient
    syscall

    li $v0, 11                          # print period character (ASCII character 46)
    li $a0, 46
    syscall


print_average_calculation_loop:
    blez $t2, print_average_exit_loop   # branch to exit if we have printed up-to specified decimal points

    mul $t0, $t0, $t3                   # multiply remainder by 10
    div $t0, $t1                        # divide (remainder * 10) by count
    mflo $a0                            # put quotient in register $a0
    mfhi $t0                            # put remainder in register $t0

    li $v0, 1                           # print quotient
    syscall

    addi $t2, $t2, -1                   # decrement decimal point counter

    b print_average_calculation_loop    # branch unconditionally to the print_average_calculation_loop

print_average_exit_loop:

print_average_end:
    jr $ra                              # jump back to the main
###########################################################
```

Comment: Which part causes you problem? Do you know how to read and write the stack? Just put the arguments on the stack in the caller, and load them back in the callee. Don't forget to allocate and deallocate the space by moving the stack pointer.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to refer to "registers" rather than "registry."